# AJAX: 301/302 header redirection (cross-domain) failing in some Webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, redirect, header, webkit, cross-domain

Trying to redirect via 302 from one server to another without content, only for tracking purpose, I worry about losing some visitors with Apple iOS devices and some Webkit/Chrome browser.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Tue, 26 Mar 2013 20:00:03 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6
Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 26 Mar 2013 20:00:03 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
P3P: CP="STP CUR OUR"
x-own: 46.163.123.40
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Location: http://target2.com
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

On Firefox and IE the  redirection is OK. Redirection from domainA to domainA is also OK. Cross-domain redirections fail on Webkit/Chrome/Mobile Safari browsers :-(

The javascript snippet looks like this:

```
testRedirection=function(url)
{
    var xmlhttp = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();//ff,webkit
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");//ie
    if(xmlhttp)
    {
        xmlhttp.open("HEAD",url,true);//tried HEAD, GET, POST
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
            {
                if(xmlhttp.status==200 || (xmlhttp.status>200 && xmlhttp.status<400))
                    alert("arrived with status "+xmlhttp.status);
                else
                    alert("failed with status "+xmlhttp.status);
            };
        };
        xmlhttp.send();
    };
    //\
};
```

Anyways, on iPhone and iPad devices and Chrome, I logged the traffic and it does never arrive with target2.com, stops without an error or warning.

This happens only with cross-domain header redirections. Is there an additional header to allow this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature. As far as the scripting is concerned (e.g. Javascript) the request is considered dangerous and is blocked. Only responses in the range >= 200 < 300 are allowed.

Comment: But, this should be allowed when the proper CORS headers are set by the domain being redirected to. But Safari doesn't seem to care about that.